# How to access a environment variable set in a jenkins job from a different jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job **Job1** that sets a environment variable say `CLIENT_CODE`.  I would like to use this variable value in a different jenkins job **Job2**, and i like to fetch this variable data from the last successful build of **Job1**.

Setting the variable is done from a shell command in **Job1**.  And **Job2** also uses shell commands to fetch this variable value.

Please let me know an approach to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. If Job2 is a downstream project of Job1, you can pass the environment variable as a parameter to the downstream project like below.

```
build job: 'path/to/downstream/project/job2', parameters: [string(name: 'PARAM1', value: "${environment-variable-to-pass-from-job1}")
```

**OR**

2. CURL your Job1 console log to get the environment variable and use it in job2 like below.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credentialID', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'password')]) {
CLIENT_CODE = sh (script: 'curl -s -u $user:$password https://job-url/job/jobName/${JOB_NUMBER}/consoleText | grep "CLIENT_CODE" | sed \'s/.*=//\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

**OR**

3. This SO thread's 1st answer: [How to set environment variable from a job and use it in next job in jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32858464/10363259)

Comment: Thank you vijay, 3rd approach is more appropriate to me.